# Laravel validation; human names for array fields

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, laravel-7

In Laravel form validation you can do this: `file_description.*` to validate each item of an array according to a set of rules. The problem is, the system automatically returns "file_description.1 is required" as an error message if the field is required and not filled in.

More on that here: https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/

Now, I'm not a complex man, I just want the field to say "File Description 1 is required". I am aware you can set messages but a) my input arrays are dynamically generated by jquery (click to add more type scenario) so I'd have to use a loop like in the above example b) I feel like there must be a better way.

Is there a way to either extend the core validation system to simply return a humanized name for the array field as Laravel does with regular fields, or is there an option I missed in the docs that allows for this? I'd rather not get involved with doing some regex type search to fix this.

Comment: It is not only common in your situation but also for **validation of CSV import** for example. Digging through the Laravel code - I can't, unfortunately, see an easier way to get it done besides the link you already provided.